# Mocking Injected Class in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, jestjs

I have 4 classes, I use 3 of those classes to instantiate one class.
Like so:

```
 const repo = new PaymentMessageRepository();
 const gorepo = new GoMessageRepository();
 const sqsm = new PaymentMessageQueueManager(process.env.SOME_ENV, process.env.ANOTHER_ENV);
 const systemUnderTest = PaymentProcessorService(repo,gorepo,sqsm);
```

The test I'd like to try is that, given that some Error is thrown by, say `repo.methodOne()`, `systemUnderTest` should return some response. For this I require to mock class `PaymentMessageRepository`. How to achieve this?

All of my classes have Joi schema attached to it, I was having troubles with that too but managed to solve with:
`jest.mock('joi')`.

Also, can you mock only for one specific test in particular? When I try to mock it looks like all my tests are grabbing the mock, should I separate them?

This is what I have so far:

```
import { PaymentMessageQueueManager } from '../Queues/PaymentMessageQueueManager';
import { PaymentMessageRepository, PaymentMessageRepository_Schema } from '../Repository/PaymentMessageRepository'
import { GoMessageRepository } from '../Services/GoMessageRepository';
import {PaymentProcessorService} from '../Services/PaymentProcessorService'

jest.mock('joi');

jest.mock('../Repository/PaymentMessageRepository', () => ({
    PaymentMessageRepository : jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => ({
        putItem: jest.fn(),
    })),
    PaymentMessageRepository_Schema: {
        required : jest.fn(),
    },
})); 

jest.mock('../Services/GoMessageRepository', () => ({
    GoMessageRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => ({
        putItem: jest.fn(),
    })),
    GoMessageRepository_Schema: {
        required: jest.fn(),
    },    
}));

jest.mock('../Queues/PaymentMessageQueueManager', () => ({
    PaymentMessageQueueManager: jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => ({
        sendToQ: jest.fn(),
    })),
    PaymentMessageQueueManager_Schema: {
            required: jest.fn(),
        }
}));


describe('PaymentProcessorService unit tests', () => {
    const env = process.env
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
        process.env = { ...env }
    });

    test('When a dependency is null, processor service should not be created', () => {
        process.env.PAYMENT_MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME = 'MOCK_TABLE_NAME';
        
        const repo = new PaymentMessageRepository();
        const gorepo = new GoMessageRepository();
        const sqsm = new PaymentMessageQueueManager(process.env.SOME_ENV, process.env.ANOTHER_ENV);
       
        expect ( () => new PaymentProcessorService(repo, undefined, sqsm)).toThrow(Error);
    })
    afterEach(() => {
        process.env = env
    });
    
    test('When mocked dependencies, processor should return no error', () => {
        const repo_mocked = new GoMessageRepository(); // <--- How to mock this so that repo_mocked.some_method() either throws or returns 0?

    })
})
```

Right now the error that I have is that the first test fails because when mocking 'Joi' it overrides the `.assert()` method and it returns true or whatever, thus even when one of the dependencies is missing, mocked joi returns OK and the assertion fails.
If I remove all of my mocks the test works as intended.

Am I mocking incorrectly? My final objective is to be able to mock one method in particular so that it returns an specific response or throws and assert accordingly, this is seamless in C# with XUnit but it's hard in TS/JS with Jest (my source files are in TS and my test files are in JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some investigation and digging I managed to mock methods of my injected classes; I don't know if this is the optimal or more elegant way to do this but it is what I came up with:

```
test('When a dependency is mocked, and message is ok, proccesor service should be created', async () =>{
        process.env.PAYMENT_MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME = 'MOCK_TABLE_NAME';
        process.env.GO_MESSAGE_TABLE_NAME = 'GO_MSG_TABLE_NAME';
        const repo = new PaymentMessageRepository();
        const sqsm = new PaymentMessageQueueManager(process.env.JAIMITO_SQS_URL_DEPOSIT, process.env.JAIMITO_SQS_URL_WITHDRA);
        const gorepo = new GoMessageRepository();

        const goRepoPutItemMock = jest
        .spyOn(GoMessageRepository.prototype, 'putItem')
        .mockImplementation(() => {
            console.log('Put Item in Go Table');
        }); // comment this line if just want to "spy"

        const repoPutItemMock = jest
        .spyOn(PaymentMessageRepository.prototype, 'putItem')
        .mockImplementation( () => {
            console.log('Put Item in Payment Table');
        });

        const queueManagerPutMessageMock = jest
        .spyOn(PaymentMessageQueueManager.prototype, 'sendToQ')
        .mockImplementation( () => {
            console.log('Sending Payment to Q');
        });

        const message = "<TransferNotification>MESSAGE_HERE</TransferNotification>";
      
        let systemUnderTest = new PaymentProcessorService(repo, gorepo, sqsm);

        let resp = await systemUnderTest.processMessages(  parsePaymentsFromEvent(constructSQSEvent(message)) );
    
        expect(repoPutItemMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(goRepoPutItemMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(queueManagerPutMessageMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(resp.batchItemFailures.length == 0).toBe(true);
    });
```

This way I can mock, for example, `goRepoPutItemMock` to throw or return specific things that I want to handle inside my systemUnderTest implementation.